# What to do with numberformatexception?

Tags: input, numberformatexception

i am making a simple guessing game that takes input from a user. The imput has to be a number that is under 6 to guess the random number. I already handled the situation if the user types a larger number with:

```
if(num > 5) {
System.out.println("The number is too high. You spoiled one turn. Your saldo is now     "     + cash +".");
guessAgain();
}
```

But for the fact that the user types something in that is not a number, i thought I could handle it with this code:

```
if(num != 1 && num != 2 && num != 3 && num != 4 && num != 5) {
System.out.println("Invalid input");
guessAgain();
}
```

But that doesnt work and gives me the numberformatexception for input string. Can you please help me out? Thanks in advance

This is the code before it:

```
System.out.print("Guess : ");

 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String gok = null;

try {
     gok = br.readLine();
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
     System.out.println("IO error");
     System.exit(1);
  }




int num = Integer.parseInt(gok);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a try catch you can use the exception to determine if it wasn't a number that was filled in. (in the try you can put a convert to a int). And most of the times there is going to be an exception with the convert it is going to be if it wasn't a number that was filled in.

EDIT:

> try
>       {
>           Integer.valueOf([here your input]);
>       }
>   catch (NumberFormatException e)
>     {
>           System.out.println("Your input was not a number");
>       }

Comment: please bear with me that im a beginner, can you show how the code should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Transform num to Integer and catch the numberFormatException like that (I just take your code and add catching nfe):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String num = null;
        try
        {
            num = br.readLine();
            Integer.valueOf(num);
        } catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("IO error");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
        System.out.println(num);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added this in my code and im still getting the error. I added the code before it as it might clear it a bit up.